# js setting default url after using history.pushstate

Tags: javascript, url, history

I have a problem. How can i remove from url "content" added by history.pushState?
For example i have a this url:

```
site.com
```

Ok, now i update this url to this:

```
site.com/site/subsite
```

How i can restore default url (site.com).

I try `history.pushState("",document.title,document.location.pathname)` but,

`document.location.pathname` is "site.com/site/subsite"

and i return to start point :(

Answer (score 5):

```
history.pushState("", document.title, "/");
```

It will remove state completely from the domain url.